# Adding aesthetics on barCharts and changing the y-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put some aesthetics on top of some of my columns in barChart (ggplot). The condition of putting aesthetics is based on p-values. If the p-values is less than 0.001, then an aesthetics is needed.

```
fruits=c("apple","orange","watermelons")
juice_content=c(10,1,1000)
weight=c(5,2,2000)
df=data.frame(fruits,juice_content,weight)
df=gather(df,compare,measure,juice_content:weight, factor_key=TRUE)
plot= ggplot(df, aes(fruits,measure, fill=compare)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

After calculating the p-value (regardless of the correctness), watermelons has a p-values less than 0.001. How can I put an aesthetics on the top of the column?

Edit: I want to add in an aesthetics like this "***".

Edit after comments in answer:

I am able to produce this plot by using the following code:

```
plot= ggplot(df, aes(fruits,measure, fill=compare)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+ scale_y_log10() + annotate(geom="text", x=c(1,2), y=c(12,2), label="***")
```

Assuming the p-value for "apple" and "orange" are significants, we can see from the plot that:
[Desire Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GQy3.png)

there are aesthetics " *** " on top of the corresponding columns.

I know how to do this manually; however, my actual data has more than 100 columns and the columns that needs to put the aesthetics " *** " on top (i.e., p-value < 0.001) are about ~34.

I don't want to do this manually; the ideal code I want will be something like: (using the provided example as an example)

1. I found the fruits "apple" and "orange" are significants
2. find the x-axis that correspond to the fruits "apple" and "orange".
3. add an aesthetics " *** " right above those columns

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what aesthetics exactly you would like to put on top of the column? Also, friendly reminder that `geom_col(...)` is shorthand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity", ...)`.

Comment: @teunbrand edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you perform the statistical test outside `ggplot` and you want to 1) add p value to the graph, and 2) change y scale: 
By the way, `plot=...` may not be the best way to assign a graph name:

Try this:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(fruits,measure, fill=compare)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())![enter image description here
p <- p + annotate(geom="text", x=2.8, y=2300, label="* P <0.001") 
p
p <- p + scale_y_log10()
p
```

You can just those values to change the position of the text.

[image]

**EDIT**
In response to your revised question, you may want to try some packages like `ggpubr` and `ggsignif`. Personally, I prefer to perform statistics testing first to get summary results, and generate graphs based on the summary results later. The trade-off of one step although convenient can be less flexible and take more time to learn new packages.

Comment: I don't want to add the p value in a specific place. For example, after calculating the p-value, I obtain the fruits "apple" and "orange" have significant p-value. Then I want to add the p-value on top of their corresponding columns.

Comment: I’m a little confused about your expected product. Could  you add a graph or be more specific?

Comment: I add in more details and a graph on the question, please take a look. Thank you!